# mysql database creation using three different txt files

Tags: mysql

I have three `.txt` file .

**First** :- 177000 entries (can say row names)[All entries in a single column]

**2nd**:-    24000 entries(columns names) [All entries in a single column]

**3rd**:-    values corresponding to 177000 rows and 24000 columns(it is around 50 gb)[it is a matrix]

how I can make a `MySQL` database with these files so that query can be done on the data in `php`.

Comment: can you give an example (with little data) of this three text file

Comment: a.txt[s1 s2 s3]  b.txt[gi g2 g3]                                                                                                    c.txt{   g1    g2    g3}
       s1  0.1  0.2   0.3
       s2  0.5  0.7   0.2
       s3  0.4  0.9   0.1

Comment: If it is Gene Sample data, see this post for mysql schema design.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005373/storing-gene-expression-data-in-mysql-junction-tables-needed]

Comment: thanks a lot ,data is sample gene expression data ..but i am facing the challenge how i can store the expression data in third table? means values corresponding to sample,gene foreign values

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you find a way of making three separate database tables and upload those data there.

Secondly you query from PHP using any of the `join` statements. `Left join, right join or inner join`, depending on what you needs are exactly.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but challenge is third file is too large ..how i can make a mysql table with large number of column names ?

Comment: Try making a .csv file with the data you have and try importing the .csv file to the MySQL database.